# React library to drag and select images in a gallery

Tags: reactjs, select, drag

Is there any reactJS library which can enable user to drag and create a rectangular box in an image gallery and the images that fall in that rectangle automatically selected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: React DnD https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/

Comment: React DnD is for drag an drop i guess. I want drag and select library. Hope its clear now @DharmendraPoonia

Comment: Something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-to-select

Answer (score 0):

try this package! not sure if this is what u need
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-drop

Comment: Nope. My requirement is a library that will enable to drag and select images. just like we can drag and select icons in any OS. Hope its clear.